# How make buildout add eggs to virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, buildout

I have to work with few *django* projects that uses *virtualenv* (and that is fine). Except its quite hard to get this virtual setup every time I want to develop something.

So I'd like to use *zc.buildout*, it would solve easy environment construction issue. Unfortunately I **must not break old *virtualenv* way of developing/deploying**.

Projects heavily rely on manage.py file.

```
/project_root
|-- virtual
|-- website
    |-- manage.py (has to access all python packages that buildout installs)
    `-- ...
```

Basically I need **buildout to install eggs to virtual/lib/python/site_packages** folder, best would be to symlink form egg cache.

Notes:

1. buildout generates django executable script that contains all required paths. This script gets installed into *virtual/bin/*.
2. I've tried [gp.recipe.pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/gp.recipe.pip), but it doesn't seem to do what I need.
3. I haven't tried [rjm.recipe.venv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rjm.recipe.venv) yet

### Solution

Its not perfect, but works:

1. collect eggs to one folder using [collective.recipe.omelette](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.omelette).
2. add __init__.py file to this folder using [cp.recipe.cmd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/cp.recipe.cmd/) (thanks to [sureshvv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587936/how-make-buildout-add-eggs-to-virtualenv/9588662#9588662)).
3. append path to this folder in required python files (in my case its manage.py).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cp.recipe.cmd and run the easy_install command with the --install-dir optiion